# Avoiding multiple JSESSIONIDs in a Jetty / OSGI / Shiro environment

Tags: java, session, jetty, osgi, shiro

Im developing a java application with OSGI and Shiro, using Jetty as the web container.
While navigating through my apllication i recognized that for different paths / osgi modules I get different JSESSIONIDs. I spend hours searching the web and debugging and could not find any solution.
My SecurityManager is shared between the modules with an osgi service.

My Shiro config:

```
    [main]
    shiro.loginUrl = /security/ui/redirect?redirectTo=login
    shiro.successUrl = /UserManagement.html

    credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
    credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
    credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 1024

    upRealm = com.sap.sse.security.UsernamePasswordRealm
    upRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher

    oauthRealm = com.sap.sse.security.OAuthRealm

    securityManager.realms = $upRealm, $oauthRealm

    sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
    securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

    sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
    securityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO

    cacheManager = com.[...].SecurityCacheManager
    securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

    [urls]
    /Login.html = anon
```

I tried different SessionDAOs and different CacheManager this didn't help either.

The SecurityManager is loaded with the following code (shiroConfiguration is the loaded Ini-file)

```
    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new WebIniSecurityManagerFactory(shiroConfiguration);
    SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

How can I avoid those multiple JSESSIONIDs?

Comment: sounds like the session isn't being stored in your cache, and the security manager thinks a new session is needed every time.